# Django crispy form layout helper does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to set the html layout of my forms using the helper and layout of crispy form. 
In other words I have set my form in the following manner.

```
class MaterialeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    data_contabile=forms.DateTimeField(widget=DatePicker(attrs={
    class Meta:
        model = Materiale
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()

        self.layout = Layout(
            Field('conta', id="form-conto", css_class="form-control", name="Conto"))
```

And after that I have set in my template the html code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                  <label for="conto"></label>
                  {{form.conto|as_crispy_field}}
```

but in the layout the id and name does not work properly. In fact if I ispect the page I try the following code:

```
<select name="conto" class="select form-control form-control" required="" id="id_conto"> <option value="">---------</option> <option value="1" selected="">Materia Prima</option>

</select>
```

where is the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am also just started using crispy forms. Trying to fix a similar issue, I noticed the layout helper only works when using:

```
{% crispy form %}
```

instead of {{ form|crispy}} or any of the template filter variants.